# Derivative of Trig Functions (Intuition Help?)

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Looking for some intuition help here.

I have the following exercise and these are the steps I take:
$$
y = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

$$
u=\frac{1}{x}
$$

$$
y = \sin u,\;\;\frac{dy}{du} = \cos u= \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

$$
u=x^{-1};\;\frac{du}{dx} =-x^{-2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}
$$

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\times\frac{du}{dx}=cos\frac{1}{x}\times-\frac{1}{x^2}
$$
This is incorrect but intuitively I want to multiply it this way.
$$
cos\frac{1}{x}\times-\frac{1}{x^2}=cos-\frac{1}{x^3}
$$

But the correct answer is:
$$
-\frac{cos-\frac{1}{x}}{x^2}
$$

Help me absorb the why so I can intuitively solve problems like these.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand the question: you're struggling with the intuition behind calculating $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: The intuition of multiplying cos1/x times -1/x^2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is where **parentheses** come in handy:

You found, correctly, $\dfrac{dy}{du}$ and $\dfrac{du}{dx}$.

But the scope of $\cos$ is restricted to its argument: $\left(\dfrac 1x\right)$ ONLY:

The FUNCTION $\dfrac{dy}{du} = \cos\left(\dfrac 1x\right)$ is multiplied by the function $\dfrac{du}{dx} = -\dfrac 1{x^2}$. That is not what you did. You multiplied *argument* of the $\cos$ function by the function $\dfrac{du}{dx} = -\dfrac{1}{x^2}$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\times\frac{du}{dx}=\left[cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]\times\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) $$ $$= -\frac 1{x^2} \cos\left(\frac 1x\right)
= -\dfrac{\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)}{x^2}$$

Comment: But why do I enclose it in brackets?

Comment: Because $\cos$ is applied to the argument $\frac 1x$ ONLY. The FUNCTION $\dfrac{dy}{du} = \cos\left(\dfrac 1x\right)$ is multiplied by the function $\dfrac{du}{dx} = -\dfrac 1{x^2}$

Comment: Thank you very much! Where could I see more of these trig argument "laws" or rules?

Comment: For example, If we have $f(x) = cos x,$ and we have $g(x) = x$, then $f(x)\cdot g(x) = \cos(x)\cdot (x) =  x\cos(x)$

Comment: @amWhy: Even nice follw ups! +1

Answer (score 0):

First, you are taking short cuts when you are writing your equations that simply confuse things.  Also, LaTeX has `\sin` and `\cos`. Start over.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Let}\quad f(x) &= \sin\frac{1}{x}.\\
\text{Let}\quad u &= \frac{1}{x}.\\
f(x) &= \sin u\\
\frac{df}{dx} &= \frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx} \quad\text{by the Chain rule}\\
\frac{df}{du} &= \cos u\\
\frac{du}{dx} &= -\frac{1}{x^2} \\
\frac{df}{dx} &= \frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx} \\
&= \cos u \cdot [-\frac{1}{x^2}] \\
&=  \cos \frac{1}{x} \cdot [-\frac{1}{x^2}]\\
&=  -\frac{1}{x^2} \cos \frac{1}{x}.
\end{aligned}
$$

By the way, you are panicking and falling into the "Universal Distributive Law of Freshmen"; you think that all operations distribute over each other, and all operations commute.  This is what has caused legions of students to replace $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ with $1 + x$.  You wrote:

$$
\cos\frac1x \cdot \frac{1}{x^2} = \cos\frac{1}{x^3}.
$$

Even though $\cos x$ looks like a product, it isn't.  Had you been using a programming language, you'd see that `COS(X)*Y` is not the same as `COS(X*Y)`.  Try any of these cases with actual numbers and a pocket calculator; you'll see what I mean.

When you panic like that, always take a deep breath and start over.  And, never write a function next to its derivative and equate them.

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me to a quick tutorial on LaTex and the correct way to write equations so I do not confuse more people?

Comment: I should have looked at this too: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117